# How do I do comparison and similar numerical operations on JuMP variables

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm new to constraint programming and I was trying to solve the group photo problem from gecode example [here](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG/photo-without-modeling-support.cpp).

The objective of the problem was to find the solution with minimum violations. Finding violations required comparison and finding absolute value.
Trying to compare the JuMP variables like:

```
@defVar(m, pos[1:n])
pos[1]>0 # Testing
```

gives me

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: `isless` has no method matching isless(::Int64, ::JuMP.GenericAffExpr{Float64,JuMP.Variable})

Is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The expression
`sum(abs(pos[spec[i][0]] - pos[spec[i][1]]) > 1)` is to be minimized.
(assuming `true` is 1 and `false` is 0).

Comment: Do you have an algebraic representation of the problem you're trying to solve? It's hard (for me) to read the linked C++ code.

Comment: Sorry to post a vague question, I was trying to be minimal in reproducing my problem. 
Anyway, using the logic in the  cpp code, the algebraic representation would be:  `abs(pos[spec[i][0]] - pos[spec[i][1]]) > 1` and it's sum over all the i's should be Minimum for optimal solution. I can't figure out how to take absolute value or do the comparison of the spec, pos variables in JuMP .

Comment: JuMP is not a constraint programming language like gecode; you can't directly use logical functions of decision variables. To use JuMP (and the solvers supported by JuMP), you'd have to reformulate the problem into likely mixed integer programming form, using indicator variables to model logical conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to reformulate that. In case JuMP doesn't satisfy the needs for this one or for any future constraint programming tasks, do you think creating a wrapper for an existing C library in Julia would be a good idea?

Comment: Definitely, it would be great to have these libraries wrapped in Julia!